# CSS Background using SVG does not show in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, background

I can't find a clear answer to this. What am I missing? I have the latest Chrome. What code etc. do you need to help me with this? I have a basic entry in CSS for adding background images. How is svg different? Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you upload your code or example. jsfidde?

Comment: Is this how you can see it? I've not used jfiddle yet. https://jsfiddle.net/newsong80/nko5q07r/#&togetherjs=vnVKaymDJI

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hodca/nko5q07r/4/ check this

Comment: Wow. You have to put all that in? Where do I get that?

Comment: i update the question with answer take a look @Newsong80

Comment: How are you loading/testing the page?  Is it locally with `file://`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use background i mage as url to your svg or as base64 content

take a look at this jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hodca/nko5q07r/7/

try this:

```
.testSVG{
   display: 100%;
    height: 193px;
  background-image:url("https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg")
}
```

Comment: I see your kiwi. :)   I am not "live" with this yet, only local. My background shows in IE, but not Chrome with the path I have to the file. So something must be right.

Comment: @Newsong80 if you find the answer helpfull please vote, thanks

Comment: I will do that for sure, when I get the answer. If the file path works in one browser, why would it not work in another?

Comment: So I've tried several things and nothing is working so far.

Comment: Which server you use ? Nodejs c#? Are you put the file at shared folder? @Newsong80

Comment: I am just on my computer now, no server.